# How to open xml by clicking button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

So I have made a new layout in **res/layout** called **about**, what I want to do is, when clicking a button i get directed to that layout.

Simplified. When I press a button on "activity_main.xml" it opens "about.xml".
How can I achieve this??? I don't have access to most resource heavy websites, Stackoverflow is my last option. So it will be appreciated if you know how.

Comment: In MainActivity by clicking a button start a new activity whose layout is about.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to start new activity, just invoke:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.about);
```

when your button is clicked. This will set for the current activity new layout located at `res/layout/about.xml`. This will work if you just change your activity presentation without changing it functionality.

If you want to launch another activity, you should create a new activity class that implements functionality of that new activity and keeps `about.xml` as its layout. On button click, you just start this new activity.

Answer (score 0):

First create an activity for about e.g AboutActivity and relate its layout with your about.xml layout.

Then Create a button on your `main.xm`l

```
Button about = (Button)findViewById(r.id.button1);

about.setOnClickListener(new view V)

{

Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext,AboutActivity.java)
StartActivity(In);
}
```

Comment: I created an ImageButton on activity_main.xml, the rest I don't really understand how to get it to work, the imagebuttons name is "settings_icon" the .xml in layout is called "about.xml" all i want to do is when i click the image button it directs me to "about.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add your **AboutActivity** in **AndroidXml.xml** deployment file.
like

```
<activity name:"AboutActivity"></activity>
```

Now use following code,

```
Button about = (Button)findViewById(r.id.button);
about.setOnClickListener(new view.OnCLickListener()
{
Intent in = new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class)
StartActivity(In);
});
```

Comment: i dont understand it though, I have an ImageButton on my "Playlist.xml", and when I click it, i want it to open "about.xml" :s I dont understand what you explained sorry v.v

Comment: use ImageButton object at the about object. OR replace about to ImageButton object